# Python mypy type checking not working as expected

Tags: python, types, mypy, bottle

I'm new to python, and am a huge fan of static type checkers. I have some code that handles file uploads with the Bottle framework. See below.

```
def transcribe_upload(upload: FileUpload) -> Alternative:
  audio:AudioSource = upload_source(upload)
  ...

def upload_source(upload:FileUpload) -> AudioSource:
  ...
```

I made a really simple mistake and passed `upload.file` (the file-like object) to `upload_source` instead of the entire `FileUpload` object.

```
def transcribe_upload(upload: FileUpload) -> Alternative:
  audio:AudioSource = upload_source(upload.file) # This is incorrect!
```

The typechecker didn't catch it. In fact, it doesn't catch ANY incorrect parameter passing to `upload_source`:

```
def transcribe_upload(upload: FileUpload) -> Alternative:
  audio:AudioSource = upload_source(4)           # Why isn't mypy giving me an error?
  audio:AudioSource = upload_source(upload.asdf) # Why isn't mypy giving me an error?
```

What's going on? I tested some basic functions separately and the typechecker caught when I tried to pass a number to a function that wanted a string, and it worked. What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

@kojiro suggsted that `FileUpload` is equivalent to `Any`. I think that may be correct. Here is the source for [`FileUpload`](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L2730). It's imported like this: `from bottle import FileUpload`.

If that's the case, why is it letting me use `FileUpload` as if it were a type? (If I mess up the name, like `FileUpld` it does give me an error).

More importantly, how do I get real types? I suppose the bottle authors have to add them?

Comment: How are you invoking `mypy` and what is its configuration?

Comment: What is `FileUpload`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This could use a [mre], `FileUpload` and `Alternative` are not provided here.

Comment: My first guess is that `FileUpload` is essentially `Any`. One could possibly find that out using [`reveal_type`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html?highlight=reveal_type#reveal-type).

Comment: @kojiro I think you're right. See edit.

Comment: `bottle` lib doesn't have a `py.typed` file so mypy is probably treating everything you import from it as `Any` type https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports You need some 3rd party type defs for the lib, but I haven't been able to find any (these can often be found in https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/main/stubs and published as a `types-<lib>` lib in PyPI)

Comment: If you can't find stubs for bottle, another solution that works pretty well is to provide a [Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) for the type you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bottle` is not a statically-typed library (it offers no type annotations in [`bottle.py`](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py)). Its organisation as a single `bottle.py` (instead of a [*package*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)) also prevents you from making a [`py.typed`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/#packaging-type-information) yourself, which would otherwise allow mypy to pick up at least the class attributes, function/method signatures, and global variables (even if they don't have any typing information).

The only way to get "real types" is for the `bottle` maintainers to add them. Assuming this isn't going to happen, you have several options:

1. Generate a skeletal outline ([Python stub file, extension `.pyi`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html)) which will aid in basic code completion. This will catch variable, function, and class *existence*, but not variable and function signature typing information (simply because `bottle.py` doesn't have any in the first place).

   The skeletal outline can be generated in about a second using mypy's shipped [`stubgen`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubgen.html) tool, which you should already have if you've installed mypy.
2. Collect runtime types by running [pyannotate](https://github.com/dropbox/pyannotate) or [MonkeyType](https://github.com/Instagram/MonkeyType) on [bottle's test suite](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/tree/master/test), and use these tools to generate a `.pyi`. This is more accurate than just running `stubgen`, but the final quality is at the mercy of the test suite, and is very likely to result in a lot of false positive warnings by mypy, especially with [descriptor classes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) like bottle's [`DictProperty`](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/99341ff3791b2e7e705d7373e71937e9018eb081/bottle.py#L189) and [`lazy_attribute`](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/99341ff3791b2e7e705d7373e71937e9018eb081/bottle.py#L230).
3. Use [pytype](https://github.com/google/pytype)'s  type inference to generate a `.pyi`. This generally results in more usable stubs, at the cost of an extremely long inference procedure that may end up building a dependency graph and scanning most of your `site-packages`, and will fail quite often if `bottle` has a lot of complex third-party dependencies. (EDIT: It looks like `bottle` only depends on the Python standard library, in which case you should get a fairly fast inference by pytype)

You should end up getting a single `bottle.pyi` that you must move to the same directory as `bottle.py`. This should be in the `site-packages` of your virtual environment. Once you've done 2. or 3., `mypy` should be able to pick up typing errors properly.